# Como puedo tener una columna mas larga que otra de la misma fila?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Ai qes el maquetado que quiero conseguir]

Lo estoy haciendo con bootstrap, digamos la cabecera (el primer div de arriba) no tengo prrblemas. 
Antes que nada decir que lo celeste como bien sabeis son las filas y lo verde las columnas, tengo dos filas :

**Primera fila** : row con dos colum
**Segunda fila**: row con dos colum tmbn, pero quiero que la columna  derecha se quede quieta que no siga creciendo hacia abajo por culpa del contenido de la del titulo del apartado y descripcion.

Entonces mi problema es que el menu se mantenga pequeño, solo que su **height** sea lo suficiente como para aabrcar su contenido, no que por fuerza se ajuste al de su hermano, porque el resultado es que como el de la izquierda tiene mas contenido este menu se alarga innecesariamente, no se si me he explicado bien.

En defninitiva, hacer que no se autoresize pero que mantenga el responsive.

No se si para arreglarlo debo echar mano de propiedades del  **CSS** .

Comment: Si puedes pon la parte del código relacionado con tu problema para intentar darte una respuesta adecuada a tu código. Por lo que dices se me ocurren varias formas de ayudarte pero antes quiero ver tu código para indicarte la más adecuada y probarlo para que se ajuste a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí varias opciones:

- la normal ambas columnas crecen
- la columna le pones máxima altura 50vh
- la columna crece igual pero se miente el fondo
- la columna crece hasta el máximo del contenido (max: fit-content)

```css
.row {
  background: cyan;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row>div {
  background: green;
  border: 5px solid cyan;
}

.row>div.sinfondo {
  background: cyan;
}

ul {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.row>div.mediaaltura {
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.row>div.fitcontent {
  max-height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <p>Foto</p>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/280/?random" alt="test">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Titulo del apartado 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in mattis magna, ac viverra ipsum. Nulla dictum hendrerit vehicula. Nunc semper mi in auctor aliquam. Donec ut magna sit amet sapien faucibus scelerisque a quis risus. Nam convallis
          eu nisl a accumsan. Praesent facilisis vitae justo a faucibus. Donec nibh lacus, feugiat non ligula sit amet, venenatis ornare diam. Cras diam lorem, placerat vel leo vitae, accumsan dictum velit. Sed tincidunt fermentum nibh, nec pretium lorem
          sagittis non. Curabitur in ullamcorper tellus. Nulla interdum consectetur justo, vel venenatis eros laoreet vel. Etiam condimentum est sapien, ut pellentesque ligula consequat nec. Cras in vestibulum ipsum. Morbi iaculis, neque quis finibus
          tristique, eros felis molestie ante, a consectetur nibh est eu ex. Aenean magna quam, iaculis eu imperdiet lacinia, semper a velit. Vivamus commodo leo vel finibus ornare. Integer ac tincidunt lorem. Nunc id lacus id nisl finibus vulputate et
          et eros.

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mediaaltura">
        <ul class="text-menu">
          <li>TITULO 1 1</li>
          <li>TITULO 2 1</li>
          <li>TITULO 3 1</li>
          <li>TITULO 4 1</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Titulo del apartado 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in mattis magna, ac viverra ipsum. Nulla dictum hendrerit vehicula. Nunc semper mi in auctor aliquam. Donec ut magna sit amet sapien faucibus scelerisque a quis risus. Nam convallis
          eu nisl a accumsan. Praesent facilisis vitae justo a faucibus. Donec nibh lacus, feugiat non ligula sit amet, venenatis ornare diam. Cras diam lorem, placerat vel leo vitae, accumsan dictum velit. Sed tincidunt fermentum nibh, nec pretium lorem
          sagittis non. Curabitur in ullamcorper tellus. Nulla interdum consectetur justo, vel venenatis eros laoreet vel. Etiam condimentum est sapien, ut pellentesque ligula consequat nec. Cras in vestibulum ipsum. Morbi iaculis, neque quis finibus
          tristique, eros felis molestie ante, a consectetur nibh est eu ex. Aenean magna quam, iaculis eu imperdiet lacinia, semper a velit. Vivamus commodo leo vel finibus ornare. Integer ac tincidunt lorem. Nunc id lacus id nisl finibus vulputate et
          et eros.

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 sinfondo">
        <ul class="text-menu">
          <li>TITULO 1 2</li>
          <li>TITULO 2 2</li>
          <li>TITULO 3 2</li>
          <li>TITULO 4 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Titulo del apartado 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in mattis magna, ac viverra ipsum. Nulla dictum hendrerit vehicula. Nunc semper mi in auctor aliquam. Donec ut magna sit amet sapien faucibus scelerisque a quis risus. Nam convallis
          eu nisl a accumsan. Praesent facilisis vitae justo a faucibus. Donec nibh lacus, feugiat non ligula sit amet, venenatis ornare diam. Cras diam lorem, placerat vel leo vitae, accumsan dictum velit. Sed tincidunt fermentum nibh, nec pretium lorem
          sagittis non. Curabitur in ullamcorper tellus. Nulla interdum consectetur justo, vel venenatis eros laoreet vel. Etiam condimentum est sapien, ut pellentesque ligula consequat nec. Cras in vestibulum ipsum. Morbi iaculis, neque quis finibus
          tristique, eros felis molestie ante, a consectetur nibh est eu ex. Aenean magna quam, iaculis eu imperdiet lacinia, semper a velit. Vivamus commodo leo vel finibus ornare. Integer ac tincidunt lorem. Nunc id lacus id nisl finibus vulputate et
          et eros.

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 fitcontent">
        <ul class="text-menu">
          <li>TITULO 1 3</li>
          <li>TITULO 2 3</li>
          <li>TITULO 3 3</li>
          <li>TITULO 4 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

En internet Explorer la de mentir el fondo es la única que responde bien.

En Firefox y Edge que soportan el max: fit-content parecieran no respetarlo.

Answer (score -1):

¿Has intentado aplicando esto en css?

```
menu{
  max-height: ()vh;
}
```

Comment: vh supongo que es una medida, yo uso siempre px, que es mejor ?

Comment: vh es una unidad, con respecto al alto del dispositivo, que va del 1 al 100, si quieres por ejemplo, que ese cuadro ocupe un máximo del 20% de la altura seria 20vh, tambien esta el vw, que seria para el ancho. si usas pixeles, que es una unidad absoluta, dejará de ser responsiva. o en todo caso también puedes usar %, que es con respecto al row  si no me equivoco: max-height: 20%.  Hay diferentes unidades pero si no quieres que crezca demás, usa max-height

Comment: parecia que me lo solucionaba pero al cambir la pantalla queda desencajado con el contenido, no hay otra manera de hacerlo ?. Porque en cuanto se cambie a un dispositivo pequeño ya el menu de la derecha le salen las letras por abajo del div yqueda muy feo

Comment: intentando con varios tag, di con max-height: fit-content;... disculpa todo el lio, o simplemente height: fit-content;